# Trigger before save an object in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reflection, spring-aop

I'm wondering how can I get the id of an object before being saved in the DB and do a treatment over it. I tried to use AOP, I created a method with `@Before` annotation that does a specific treatment before executing the spring data save method.

The method below displays this error :

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: id

```
@Before("execution(* com.next.commerce.back.repository.*.save(..)) && args(object)")
public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object object) {
    Field field = null;
    Class<? extends Object> clazz = object.getClass();
    try {
        field = clazz.getDeclaredField("id");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(object, getNextValue("Test"));
        logger.info("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" + (Long) field.get(field));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error", e);
    }
}
```

Example of entity:

```
@Document(collection = "address")
public class Address extends Identity<Long> implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private Integer zipCode;

  private String country;

//getter and setter
}

public class Identity<ID extends Serializable> {

  @Id
  private ID id;

  public ID getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(ID id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you really have to use reflection? Do the objects containing the `id` field not have any setter methods? And do they not have anything in common, e.g. implement the same interface or have a common base class? In those cases you could work without reflection if you change your aspect a bit. Let me know, then maybe I can help you get rid of this ugly reflection code. What you are doing here is unstable and also abuse of AOP.

Comment: @kriegaex i didn't find a solution other that the use of reflection. All the entities extend from a class identity that contains only an id with getter and setter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your question update in response to my comment I would suggest something like this:

**Helper classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(FIELD)
public @interface Id {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
public @interface Document {
  String collection();
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Identity<ID extends Serializable> {
  @Id private ID id;

  public Identity(ID id) { this.id = id; }
  public ID getId() { return id; }
  public void setId(ID id) { this.id = id; }
  @Override public String toString() { return "Identity [id=" + id + "]"; }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Document(collection = "address")
public class Address extends Identity<Long> implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private Integer zipCode;
  private String country;

  public Address(Long id, Integer zipCode, String country) {
    super(id);
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
    this.country = country;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Address [id=" + getId() + ", zipCode=" + zipCode + ", country=" + country + "]";
  }
}
```

**Driver application:**

```
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public void save(Identity identity) {
    System.out.println("Saving " + identity);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application application = new Application();
    application.save(new Identity<Long>(1L));
    application.save(new Address(2L, 12345, "Germany"));
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.util.Random;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

import de.scrum_master.app.Identity;

@Aspect
public class IdSetterAspect {
  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

  @Before("execution(* de.scrum_master..save(..)) && args(identity)")
  public void beforeAdvice(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, Identity identity) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    System.out.println("  Old ID = " + identity.getId());
    identity.setId(RANDOM.nextInt(1000));
    System.out.println("  New ID = " + identity.getId());
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.save(Identity))
  Old ID = 1
  New ID = 514
Saving Identity [id=514]
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.save(Identity))
  Old ID = 2
  New ID = 995
Saving Address [id=995, zipCode=12345, country=Germany]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but for me the ID is auto increment, i don't enter it manually. so it's enough to save the address only like this:application.save(new Address(12345, "Germany"))

Comment: That was only an example!!! I don't use a database or Spring or any framework when answering questions here, I am producing stand-alone examples, so-called [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As a developer you are surely able to just change the lines you don't like. Just put whatever code you like into the aspect and change the pointcut to fit your package structure and you are all set. Then please accept and upvote my answer because it solves your problem - as promised, without reflection. This is more elegant and has better performance.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
try {
      Field field = Class.forName(object.getClass().getName()).getDeclaredField("id");
      field.setAccessible(true);
      logger.info("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" + (Long) field.get(object));
} catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Error", e);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but unfortunately does not explain what the actual problem is and how to solve it. Instead you refactored the code, hiding the actual relevant change. So I am explaining it for the OP's benefit: `field.get(field)` is wrong, you need to call `field.get(object)` as described in the [Java SE API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-).